# Object not initialized not sure why

Tags: java, file, exception, io

I'm trying to read some stuff from a text file. The .txt file and and code is all within my current working directory. I'm getting the error fInput may not have been initialized. I believe this is because my program is going to my catch statement and the not the try.

Here is my code segment:

```
Scanner fInput;
        try {
            fInput = new Scanner(new File("accountData.txt"));
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: File Not Found.");
        }
        while(fInput.hasNext()) {
            String tempID = fInput.next();
            String tempFName = fInput.next();
            String tempLName = fInput.next();
            String tempPNumber = fInput.next();
            String tempEmail = fInput.next();

            System.out.println(tempID+""+tempFName+""+tempLName+""+tempPNumber+""+tempEmail);
        }
```

Could anybody shed some light on why I'm getting this? Thanks.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels actually that isn't the problem here. It's a compiler error caused by a lack of initialization.

Comment: Yes, we can shed light on it. DO NOT IGNORE EXCEPTIONS! Printing the exception and continuing as-if nothing happened, is still *ignoring* it. Ok, that doesn't directly explain your problem, but fixing that will also fix your compilation error.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for your input. I've edited the .txt file name to include the path to where the executable is, and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @NickM: initialize the variable when you declare it with a `null`. For my money, I would  avoid using File with a Scanner and instead use a URL obtained via resources.

Comment: @Andreas I was not necessarily ignoring the exception, I just knew it was getting to that point for the wrong reasons. But I get what you're saying and I understand it's better coding practice to do so. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yikes, can't believe I didn't notice I took out the null. Thanks. Yes I agree, but my prof is requiring us to use Scanner for this assignment. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @NickM: yes, use Scanner, but you can use it with resources rather than files. If you do that, then the path is relative to the class files, not the "user.dir", and you have an easier time when creating JAR files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the issue is that if an exception is thrown in your `try` block, then `fInput` will not be initialized after the `catch`. Therefore, the compiler has no guarantee that `fInput` will be initialized by the time it gets to your `while` loop. If you still prefer to use a `Scanner` in this way, you can fix your current code in two ways:

1. Run your loop in the `try`:

   ```
   Scanner fInput;
   try {
       fInput = new Scanner(new File("accountData.txt"));
       while(fInput.hasNext()) {
           String tempID = fInput.next();
           String tempFName = fInput.next();
           String tempLName = fInput.next();
           String tempPNumber = fInput.next();
           String tempEmail = fInput.next();                
           System.out.println(tempID+""+tempFName+""+tempLName+""+tempPNumber+""+tempEmail);
       }
   }
   catch(Exception e) {
       System.out.println("ERROR: File Not Found.");
   }
   ```
2. Ensure null safety with a check:

   ```
   Scanner fInput = null; //This change is important!
   try {
       fInput = new Scanner(new File("accountData.txt"));
   }
   catch(Exception e) {
       System.out.println("ERROR: File Not Found.");
   }
   if(fInput!=null) {
       while(fInput.hasNext()) {
           String tempID = fInput.next();
           String tempFName = fInput.next();
           String tempLName = fInput.next();
           String tempPNumber = fInput.next();
           String tempEmail = fInput.next();
           System.out.println(tempID+""+tempFName+""+tempLName+""+tempPNumber+""+tempEmail);
       }
   }
   ```

Either of these will avoid the dreaded `NullPointerException` in your example.

Comment: Much appreciated. Thanks for the explanation.